# How to create image that resize according to the frame in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How to create image that resize according to the frame in Tkinter Python ?
I have a frame with image in, and i want the image will stretch all over the frame, and when the frame change the size, the image will change the size according to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<Configure>` event binding.  The `<Configure>` event fires when a widget gets resized.  For example:

```
root.bind('<Configure>', resizeImage)
```

To get your image's current container size, use

```
w, h = frame.winfo_width, frame.winfo_height
```

Then use `w` and `h` to resize and update your image.